# Setting Digital clock in Native App using Selenium and Appium

Tags: android, selenium, appium, clock, sendkeys

I want to set the digital clock in my native app during automation using Selenium and Appium.As I want to set the time manually.The clock is 12hour based clock.As I am able to set four digit clock i.e (10:30pm) etc..But unable to set 3 digit i.e (3:30pm) whenever i set to 3 digit it gives me the view like this (-3:30pm)..

Please help me to set time manually through sendkeys or any other method using appium and selenium.

As I can send you the snapshots of my activity where I want To set time...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y1uI.png)

Comment: Please show us the code that you use to successfully set a 4 digit time.  Then we can help you adapt it to 3 digit times.

Comment: androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@index='0']")).sendKeys("1040");
        androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@index='5']")).sendKeys("PM");

Comment: And did you try setting the 3 digit time like this?
androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@index='0']")).sendK‌​eys("0330");

Comment: Actually I have tried earlier but 0 is not acceptable in that element !! Is there any other Selenium method by which we can operate Analogue Clock forks ??